# Excel macro to copy range from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba, range

I've got a problem with copying range from one sheet to another. Im trying to do it with code below

```
Sub zaladuj()
    Dim PND, DR As Worksheet
    Set PND = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2")
    Set DR = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim copyRng As Range, pasteRng As Range

    row = 4
    Do Until IsEmpty(DR.Cells(row, 2))
        row = row + 1
    Loop
    With DR
         Set copyRng = Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(row, 5))
    End With

    With PND
        Set pasteRng = Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(row, 5))
    End With

    copyRnd.Copy pasteRng

End Sub
```

However after running macro, nothing happens. As far as I noticed, whole functions runs only in sheet2. Whole macro is placed in sheet2 objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`With` on its own does nothing. You need the dots in front of the rangest to tie them to the object following the With statement.

```
Option Explicit

Sub zaladuj()
    Dim PND As Worksheet, DR As Worksheet
    Set PND = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2")
    Set DR = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
    Dim row As Long
    Dim copyRng As Range, pasteRng As Range

    row = 4
    Do Until IsEmpty(DR.Cells(row, 2))
        row = row + 1
    Loop
    With DR
         Set copyRng = .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(row, 5))
    End With

    With PND
        Set pasteRng = .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(row, 5))
    End With

    copyRng.Copy pasteRng

End Sub
```

---

Note also that

```
Dim PND, DR As Worksheet
```

declares `PND` as `Variant` - see amendment above.

---

Use `Long` rather than `Integer` as Excel has many more rows than `Integer` can handle.

---

You can probably replace with your `Do` loop with

```
row=DR.Cells(rows.count, 2).end(xlup).row
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However from now on, the code you provided ends with runtime 424 object required.

Comment: On which line? What's the value of `row`?

Comment: You had a typo in the last line. Always use Option Explicit to catch these problems.

Comment: row value is 90, error is with `copyRng.Copy pasteRng`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what to do expect?

**EDITED CODE**

```
Option Explicit

Sub zaladuj()

    Dim PND As Worksheet, DR As Worksheet
    Dim row As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set DR = .Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set PND = .Sheets("Sheet2")
    End With

    row = 4

    Do Until IsEmpty(DR.Cells(row, 2))

        DR.Range(DR.Cells(3, 1), DR.Cells(row, 5)).Copy PND.Range(PND.Cells(3, 1), PND.Cells(row, 5))

        row = row + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```